# Making permanent modprobe changes

Tags: 14.04, drivers

I have a module which doesn't work unless I first unload a different module:

```
modprobe -r bdc_pci
modprobe facetimehd
```

Running these commands (sudo) works fine, and my webcam then works as expected. But now I want to make that change permanent.

The other posts I've seen about making modprobe changes permanent all revolve around making a *new* module permanent, but what I'm not sure about it how to do that while also ensuring the bdc_pci module is unloaded first. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to create a separate `conf` file to blacklist a module. This way it will be easier to find or revert this setting.

Run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bdc_pci.conf <<< "blacklist bdc_pci"
```

That will stop `bdc_pci` module from loading at startup.

To auto load `facetimehd`, run:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/modules <<< "facetimehd"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you dont't want to load `bdc_pci` module add it to blacklist in:
`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` on the end of this file like this:

```
blacklist bdc_pci
```

(or you can create your own file eg. *blacklist-bdc_pci.conf*)

Then in `/etc/modules` you can add what module you want to load, so you need to edit this file and add:

```
facetimehd
```